# Is there a way to merge two numpy arrays by only keeping the largest distance from a third array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I haven't found a good way to do this.

Say I have 3 arrays

```
Base = [1,2,3]
A = [1,4,-5]
B = [3,-2,4]
```

I want to merge A and B such that only the largest distance from Base is kept. Ie, the result would be

```
C = [2,-4,-8]
```

I'm sure there's a way to do it with numpy, I just haven't been able to find it. Thank you in advance if you can help (:

Comment: How do you compute the largest distance in this case?

Comment: Distance of A from Base is A-Base, so [0,2,-8]. B from Base is B-Base, so [2,-4,1]. Merging A and B I want to get the largest absolute distances while retaining negatives, so [2,-4,-8]

Comment: @WilliamGazeley Did either of the posted solutions work for you? Consider accepting the one that worked best for you?

Comment: Yes, your solution worked perfectly. I was sure I commented thanking you, but stackoverflow wouldn't let me accept your solution.There was some timer. Thanks again, you really saved my skin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned arrays, so going with those and hence a NumPy way with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) -

```
# Inputs
In [42]: Base = np.array([1,2,3])
    ...: A = np.array([1,4,-5])
    ...: B = np.array([3,-2,4])

In [43]: dA,dB = A-Base, B-Base

In [45]: np.where(np.abs(dA)>np.abs(dB), dA, dB)
Out[45]: array([ 2, -4, -8])
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [numpy.argmax](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html):

```py
import numpy as np

Base = np.array([1,2,3])
A = np.array([1,4,-5])
B = np.array([3,-2,4])

T = np.vstack([A,B])
ids = np.argmax(np.abs(T-Base), axis=0)

C = (T-Base)[ids, np.arange(T.shape[1])]
C
array([ 2, -4, -8])
```